# Idiomatic way of storing largest value in a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

Suppose you have variable `let maximum = 0;` and you do something like this:

```
for (let someObject of Objects) {
  maximum = someObject.value > maximum ? someObject.value : maximum;
}
```

I consider this code to be quite ugly. The goal is simply to overwrite `maximum` if a larger value comes along. However, to do this, you must repeat both `someObject.value` and `maximum` twice each, which is verbose and annoying to read.

My question: is there a more idiomatic or elegant way to write this?

This doesn't work but, if `>>` wasn't a bitwise operator and was something else instead, one could write:

```
maximum >> someObject.value;
```

which is far more elegant. Does something like this exist in Typescript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Map and spread into `Math.max`:

```
const maximum = Math.max(0, ...Objects.map(o => o.value));
```

Comment: One disadvantage of this scheme is that it creates a temporary array and passes that array to `Math.max()`.  Not optimal if the array is large.

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't see the question as asking about optimizing performance but as being idiomatic or elegant.  Almost all functional programming techniques in JavaScript will end up creating temporary arrays.

Comment: I'm just pointing out a potential drawback.  I didn't downvote, it's just a comment on using this scheme that I think is worth pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

This creates a second array but hopefully satisfies your requirement of elegance:

```ts
const maximum = Objects.map(o => o.value).reduce((p, c)=>Math.max(p,c));
```

This reduces the original array but is unwieldy:

```ts
const maximum = Objects.reduce((m, {value}) => Math.max(m, value), 0);
```

A utility function could be more clearer:

```ts
const maximum = maxSelect(Objects, o=>o.value);

function maxSelect<T>(a: Array<T>, select: (t:T)=>number) {
  return a.reduce((m, c) => Math.max(m, select(c)), Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
}
```

or you can just write:

```ts
for (let someObject of Objects) {
  maximum = Math.max(maximum, someObject.value);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that first version is always safe?  `.reduce()` is passing four arguments to `Math.max`.  In addition to the next value and the accumulator, it's also passing the index and a reference to the array.  It seems to me that the `index` argument could mess things up.

Comment: Oh man, I always fall for this trap, you're right. It could've been so nice.

Comment: @kyle_aoki - If you're using the first solution here, make sure you pick up the latest edit because the original had a problem.  Also, note for very large arrays, this creates two temporary arrays of full length.